# Getting the largest value of a row among multiple entries

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

My question is similar to the following post:
[Find largest value among repeated entries in an sql table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35565309/find-largest-value-among-repeated-entries-in-an-sql-table)

but it is for mysql and and I cannot understand how it translates in sqlite.

I want to get the max value of `pages` from my table `metadata` with multiple `file_ids` and multiple entries

My table with the two columns I am interested in.

```
file_id  pages
1          2
1          5
2          10
3          20 
4          12
4          1
5          4
6          5
6          14 
7          12
```

What I am looking for is

```
file_id  pages
1          5
2          10
3          20 
4          12
5          4
6          14 
7          12
```

I am trying to make a query but don't know how

```
String[]cols = {"file_id","pages"};
String groupBy = {"pages"};
```

all others params are `null`
that's as far as I can think.

What will be the query like. Please help.

I want the query in normal sqlite format rather than the raw query if possible.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM metadata WHERE pages = (SELECT MAX(pages) FROM metadata)` ?

Comment: ok how about in the format that I wrote in...no problem with a raw query but I would like to know how it would be in the normal query format. Thanks for your comment

Comment: Taseer I dont see any mention of  `file_id` in your query

Comment: `SELECT file_id, max(pages) FROM metadata GROUP BY file_id ORDER BY file_id`

Comment: nope shawn.... Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it. I don't understand what I am missing

Comment: I reset my app and read one pdf twice with different pages first time it was 10 pages and the second was 20, so I was supposed to get 20 as the max but I get the above error with your query and when I checked the cursor size the size is 2 instead of 1 as like I said I opened the same pdf twice which has the dame file_id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This uses the [`query()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase#query(boolean,%2520java.lang.String,%2520java.lang.String%5B%5D,%2520java.lang.String,%2520java.lang.String%5B%5D,%2520java.lang.String,%2520java.lang.String,%2520java.lang.String,%2520java.lang.String)) method:

```
String tableName = "metadata";
String[] cols = {"file_id", "max(pages) AS pages"}; 
String[] groupBy = {"file_id"};
Cursor cursor = db.query(tableName, cols, null, null, groupBy, null, null);
```

Replace `db` with your SQLiteOpenHelper variable.

Comment: I'll give it a try I think the group by does not have the parenthesis and can you please upvote my question to make it 0 idk why someone had to downvote it.

Comment: Edited, groupBy needs to be an array and needs the square brackets, right.

Answer (score 1):

Strange M D's query runs. Only group key and aggregate column can be in select list, if you use group by. So pages is invalid select column.

Correct query should be

```
SELECT file_id, MAX(pages) from tbl_test GROUP BY file_id
```

Comment: Not strange that it runs; that's just how sqlite works. From [the documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/lang.html): *Each expression in the result-set is then evaluated once for each group of rows. If the expression is an aggregate expression, it is evaluated across all rows in the group. Otherwise, it is evaluated against a single arbitrarily chosen row from within the group.*

Answer (score 0):

How about this

> SELECT DISTINCT file_id, pages from tbl_test GROUP BY file_id

Result

[image]

Comment: That won't work; using a non-grouped, non-aggregate value in a grouped select will pick an arbitrary row from the group for the values. OP wants the maximum page value. See my comment in the top level question for what it should be.

Comment: @Shawn I am not sure what OP exactly want. He is changing statement. My SQL command produced result as per OP mentioned in section of What **I am looking for is**